# Why does Resharper 4.5 testrunner sometimes take forever to start my mstests?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper, mstest

I just copied a Visual Studio solution over from another computer. I haven't done any changes, but the Resharper testrunner takes forever to start up my mstests. When the tests are finally running, they run fast.

There's a JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.exe which consumes 48% of my total cpu on my dual core.

Visual Studio's internal test runner runs them all instantly.

(VS 2008, R# 4.5.1281 on Windows Vista 64. The other computer without the problems runs on Windows 7 RC.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this reply in my mailbox today:

> This is a known problem and we're
>   doing our best to fix it. I'll let you
>   know as soon as a fix will become
>   available

Let's hope soon is not far away.

Comment: have you considered moving to nUnit and avoid the awful mstests altogether?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option from where I sit.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider asking JetBrains why this happens

http://www.jetbrains.com/support/resharper/index.html

Comment: I did that too. Still waiting for an answer, however I was hoping someone here already knew the solution.